# Neural Network - convert model output to the predicted target class

Tags: python, neural-network

I am building a neural network from scratch in python.

In the dataset I am using for testing, the features are all numeric (57 features) and the target variable is categorical (10 classes, already converted it to numeric from 0-9, but can use other encoding).
Everything seems to be working, except that I am quite stuck on how to compare my model output with the y_true value to compute the error. So I have 10 classes for the target variable and what I get as output is an array of 10-elements for each observation, instead of a unique value/classification for each sample.

Can someone give me a simple way to convert my output to a single y_predicted value that's comparable with the y_true?

I am trying not to use any libraries except for Numpy and pandas, so using Keras SparseCategoricalCrossentropy() is not an option.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a loss? I am not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So neural networks don't return the class labels as we know it. They return probabilities of the input belonging to all the classes. Naturally, these probabilities sum up too 1.
Suppose you have 4 classes: A, B, C and D.
if the true label of an input is B, the NN output will not looks like this:

```
output = [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

It will look like this:

```
output = [0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1]
```

Where the chance of input belonging to class A is 10%, class B is 60%, class C is 20% and class D is 10%.

You can easily make sure that this array sums up to 1 by adding the array elements and dividing each element by the sum. Then, you can use numpy argmax to get the index of the highest probability.
If you don't need the probabilities, then you can skip converting the output such that the sum is 1 and directly apply numpy argmax to get the index of the class with the highest probability.